# Using TIN Interpolation algorithm in PyQGIS

Tags: raster, pyqgis, tin

I was doing Tin interpolation using pyqgis, and this algorithm has this complex param called **INTERPOLATION_DATA**, where I'm stuck to create a valid string by the documentation described.

From what the documentation described:
https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/interpolation.html?highlight=tininterpolation#tin-interpolation

```
Vector layer(s) and field(s) to use for the interpolation, coded in a string (see the ParameterInterpolationData class in InterpolationWidgets for more details).
The following GUI elements are provided to compose the interpolation data string:

Vector layer [vector: any]
Interpolation attribute [tablefield: numeric]: Attribute to use in the interpolation
Use Z-coordinate for interpolation [boolean]: Uses the layer’s stored Z values (Default: False)
For each of the added layer-field combinations, a type can be chosen:

> Points
> Structured lines
> Break lines

In the string, the layer-field elements are separated by '::|::'. The sub-elements of the layer-field elements are separated by '::~::'.
```

Then I checked the source code on GitHub:

```
class ParameterInterpolationData(QgsProcessingParameterDefinition):

    def __init__(self, name='', description=''):
        super().__init__(name, description)
        self.setMetadata({
            'widget_wrapper': 'processing.algs.qgis.ui.InterpolationWidgets.InterpolationDataWidgetWrapper'
        })

    def type(self):
        return 'idw_interpolation_data'

    def clone(self):
        return ParameterInterpolationData(self.name(), self.description())

    @staticmethod
    def parseValue(value):
        if value is None:
            return None

        if value == '':
            return None

        if isinstance(value, str):
            return value if value != '' else None
        else:
            return ParameterInterpolationData.dataToString(value)

    @staticmethod
    def dataToString(data):
        s = ''
        for c in data:
            s += '{}::~::{}::~::{:d}::~::{:d};'.format(c[0],
                                                       c[1],
                                                       c[2],
                                                       c[3])
        return s[:-1]
```

I tried to run the algorithm directly from built-in panel and checked how it would look like. This is the INTERPOLATION_DATA param I got for log history.

```
# I've beautified it for better readability
{
    'INTERPOLATION_DATA':
        'Point?crs=EPSG:4326&
        field=fid:long(0,0)&field=SiteName:string(0,0)&            # Looks like it's just field name parsed to differet encoding from here
        field=1110416%E6%97%A5%E5%B9%B3%E5%9D%87:double(0,0)&  
        field=1110601%E6%97%A5%E5%B9%B3%E5%9D%87:double(0,0)&    
        field=1110401%E6%97%A5%E5%B9%B3%E5%9D%87:double(0,0)&
        field=1110616%E6%97%A5%E5%B9%B3%E5%9D%87:double(0,0)&
        field=1110216%E6%97%A5%E5%B9%B3%E5%9D%87:double(0,0)&
        field=1110201%E6%97%A5%E5%B9%B3%E5%9D%87:double(0,0)&
        field=1110501%E6%97%A5%E5%B9%B3%E5%9D%87:double(0,0)&
        field=1110516%E6%97%A5%E5%B9%B3%E5%9D%87:double(0,0)&
        field=1110301%E6%97%A5%E5%B9%B3%E5%9D%87:double(0,0)&
        field=1110116%E6%97%A5%E5%B9%B3%E5%9D%87:double(0,0)&
        field=1110316%E6%97%A5%E5%B9%B3%E5%9D%87:double(0,0)&
        field=1110101%E6%97%A5%E5%B9%B3%E5%9D%87:double(0,0)&       # until here 
        uid={a0d8c6d8-b18d-4208-96a7-07921ff9f6c3}::~::0::~::2::~::0' 
}
```

I believe the the only `2` between ::~:: is where the index of field I want to use for interpolation field, which is 2. However, I'm definitely not hard coding the field in string (#comments parts).

In short, back to the question, if given layer(type=QgsVectorLayer), how do I get the INTERPOLATION_DATA from the layer?

---

p.s. The solution I came up with is by

1. defining QgsInterpolator

```
    layer_data = QgsInterpolator.LayerData()
    layer_data.source = ob
    layer_data.zCoordInterpolation = False
    layer_data.interpolationAttribute = 2
    layer_data.sourceType = QgsInterpolator.SourcePoints
    interpolation_method = QgsTinInterpolator.Linear
    ncols, nrows = 100, 100
    extent = ob.extent()

    tin_interpolator = QgsTinInterpolator([layer_data], interpolation_method)
```

2. Export to tif and load it back

```
    export_path = f'{path}.tif'
    output = QgsGridFileWriter(tin_interpolator, 
                               export_path, 
                               extent, 
                               ncols,
                               nrows)
    output.writeFile()
    
    rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(uri, 'name')
```

That... seems like an extra steps. The ideal way should be getting the output from algorithm output, right? (`rlayer = processing.run("algorithm_id", {parameter_dictionary})['OUTPUT']`)

Comment: Whats your question? You search for a answer how to get the index of a field?