# PostGIS TIN to Raster

Tags: raster, postgis, tin

I am trying to convert a TIN to raster, in PostGIS, with a 1m cell size but sampling the tin for elevations is very slow. My test data is about 2km x 2km  and relatively flat, think farm field. Below is the sql I am using to sample the tin for elevations.

```
with grid as
    (select st_centroid(grid) as pixelCentroid from
        (select st_transform((ST_SquareGrid(1,
        st_transform(ST_SetSRID(geometry, 4326), 3857))).geom, 4326) as grid
     from boundary WHERE "Id" = 2) as grid
     inner join boundary on st_intersects(grid, geometry))

select st_intersection(pixelCentroid, tinGeom)
    from
(select 2 as id,  (st_dump(ST_DelaunayTriangles(ST_collect(geometry_4326),0, 0))).geom as tinGeom
FROM survey_points 
WHERE layer_id = 2 AND type IN (0,3)) as tin
inner join grid
on st_intersects(pixelCentroid, tinGeom)
```

I have experimented with storing the tin and indexing it but it didnt help.

Is there a way, within PostGIS, to speed up the intersection or calculate a raster cell directly from the TIN?

Comment: Somehow I was looking at the 2.2 documentation and completely missed st_interpolateraster because its not available until 3.2. It seems like exactly what I need but I am struggling to get it to create an output that makes sense. http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/RT_ST_InterpolateRaster.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to avoid having to convert the tin to raster by using a raster interpolation to create the raster directly using Delaunay triangulation. I was able to use [ST_InterpolateRaster](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/RT_ST_InterpolateRaster.html) with the option 'linear:radius=-1:nodata=0' and it creates the raster in 20 seconds which I can live with.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using ST_DumpPoints function instead of ST_Dump to sample the elevations from the TIN as it makes the process faster by reducing the number of triangle that need to be processed:
https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html

Alternatively, calculating a raster cell directly from the TIN is achievable using TIN based interpolation. Refer: [Using TIN Interpolation algorithm in PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/435094/using-tin-interpolation-algorithm-in-pyqgis)

Comment: I need the raster cell to be calculated based on the centroids location on the tin. If I dump the tin to points I would have to do the elevation interpolation myself. I'll experiment with the idea.

Comment: I also, need to perform the raster creation within PostGIS if at all possible. This is is going in a cloud application and I want to avoid moving the datasets back and forth for processing if possible. I tried QGIS's tin Interpolation and it does create what I need.